# How can I determinate invoke of keyboard in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I have a textBox, how can I make the keyBoard appear in 500 milliseconds. Is it possible?

Comment: Appears after a tap or after launch a page?

Comment: Altering the behaviour of standard controls (like this) is VERY RARELY a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, at least not directly.  If you work around it, your users won't be expecting that behaviour and it may lead to trouble.

**WARNING - Here be dragons!**

I guess you could spoof it if you really wanted to do it (which I wouldn't recommend).  You could exactly position a transparent rectangle over the control, and on tap of that control, start a timer that hides the rectangle and sets focus on the textbox, but that's a road to nightmares as you try to position the control, and re-enable it on blur.